# Program doesn't print everything I want it to

Tags: c++, output

I am writing a program that is supposed to take information about different videos as input and then print all of this information out (this output is supposed to be sorted, but I haven't gotten to that part yet). My problem is that when I end the input, it doesn't print the information of every video but only the last video.

I am new to programming and just can't figure this out at all.

This is my main.cpp file:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

#include "video.h"

int main() {

  const int MAX = 100;
  Video *video[MAX];  //up to 100 videos

  for(int l = 0; l < MAX; l++)
    {
      video[l] = NULL;
    }

  string title;
  string url;
  string desc;
  string sorting;
  float length;
  int rate;

  cout << "What sorting method would you like to use?" << endl;
  getline(cin, sorting);
  cout << "Enter the title, the URL, a comment, the length, and a rating for each video" << endl;

  while(getline(cin, title))
    {
      getline(cin, url);
      getline(cin, desc);
      cin >> length;
      cin >> rate;
      cin.ignore();
    }

for(int k = 0; k < MAX; k++)
{
video[k] = new Video(title, url, desc, length, rate);
}

  video[MAX-1]->print();


return 0; }
```

And this is my video.cpp file:

```
#include "video.h"

#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

Video::Video(string title, string url, string desc, float length, int rate)
 : m_title(title), m_url(url), m_desc(desc), m_length(length), m_rate(rate)

 {
 }


void Video::print() {
    cout << m_title << ", " << m_url <<  ", " << m_desc << ", " <<  m_length;
    cout << ", ";

    for(int y=0; y < m_rate; y++)
    {
    cout << "*";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your line `video[MAX-1]->print();` says:

"Take the element of video with the number MAX-1 (which is the last element) and call its `print()`-function."

If you want to print every video, you need another for-loop just as you did before when filling your array.

Btw: you fill your array with always the same information, is this what you want?

**Edit** for your input use something like this:

```
int k=0;

while(getline(cin, title))
{
  getline(cin, url);
  getline(cin, desc);
  cin >> length;
  cin >> rate;
  cin.ignore();
  video[k] = new Video(title, url, desc, length, rate);
  k++;
}
```

If you first execute the while-loop your variables will contain only the last read value and all videos will have the same information.

Comment: No, I want to fill the array with as many different videos as the user inputs. Each element should hold the information of a different video.

Comment: `for(int s = 0; s  < MAX; s++)
{
video[s]->print();
}`     is this what I'm supposed to use?

Comment: The output now looks find, but after it prints all the videos out, there is a segmentation fault error. Any idea why it says that after it works fine?

Comment: You are trying to print MAX Videos, but you created less, since you probably didn't input 100. so for the print-loop use `s < k`as condition with the same k you used for input. And afterwards every element you created with `new` should be deleted with `delete`. So another for loop from 0 to k ......

Comment: Thank you so much, I really really appreciate it.